# MinIO bucket for Artifactory storage

Tags: ubuntu, minio, artifactory

Am trying to configure Jfrog Artifactory to use a MinIO bucket to store data (repositories)

After following the guides for a S3 configuration.  Using this configuration, just noticed that the Artifactory is not storing the data in the bucket. Using the documentation example: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/s3-object-storage just configured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config version="2">
    <chain>
        <provider id="cache-fs" type="cache-fs">
            <provider id="s3-storage-v3" type="s3-storage-v3"/>
        </provider>
    </chain>
    <provider id="s3-storage-v3" type="s3-storage-v3">
       <endpoint>10.8.250.207</endpoint>
       <bucketName>artifactory-data</bucketName>
       <identity>BucketUser</identity>
       <credential>PASSWORD</credential>
    </provider>
</config>
```

Have any of you ever tried this?
many thanks in advance.

lost sysadmin